# Why can't I generate an Ionic React application in an Nx workspace using the nxtend plugin?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, nrwl-nx

I would like to generate an [Ionic React application](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) in an [Nx](https://nx.dev/) workspace. Therefore I used the [`@nxtend/ionic-react`](https://nxtend.dev/docs/ionic-react/getting-started) plugin that claims to be able to do exactly that.

I bootstrapped my Nx workspace with:

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest --preset empty
```

Then I installed the required dependencies according to the [`@nxtend/ionic-react` docs](https://nxtend.dev/docs/ionic-react/getting-started):

```
npm install --save-dev --exact @nxtend/ionic-react @nxtend/capacitor @nrwl/react
```

Finally, I tried to generate the application like so:

```
nx generate @nxtend/ionic-react:application myApp
```

Which results in this error:

> >  NX   Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/app-root'
>
> Require stack:
> ...

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that `@nxtend/ionic-react` does not support Nx v14 (yet).
But another plugin called [Nxext](https://nxext.dev/) does.

Nxext has a beautiful step-by-step guide in the docs how to [migrate from Nxtend to Nxext](https://nxext.dev/docs/ionic-react/migrating-from-nxtend.html).